# How can I determine the mime-type of a document using javascript only?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mime-types

I need to determine the mime-type of certain files that get returned from the service, I do not know their file extensions or what their type is before hand, basically we retrieve documents from the API like such: "http://site.com/getFile/BFD843DFLKXJDF" where the random text at the end is some file.

```
<input type="button" value="Click Me" onClick="alert(document.getElementById('iframeID').contentDocument.contentType);">

<iframe id="iframeID" src="http://site.com/getFile/BFD843DFLKXJDF" width="600" height="600" />
```

This works in Firefox, it returns in the alert dialog: "application/pdf" for pdf files. However Internet Explorer is the main browser I need to target, "contentDocument" is not defined (apparently I use just "document" instead), but "contentType" is also undefined and I don't know what the IE equivalent would be (google searches have not yielded any results).

Help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Hi did you ever find a nice way to do this?
I'm facing the same problem. I am planning on using JavaScript to get the mime type based on the file extension. Did you find/write any function that does this lookup?

Answer (score 2):

If http://site.com is different than your domain, you won't be able to access its data on any browser. This is because of Cross-site scripting security measures.

Comment: site.com is the same domain, but I only have access to the front-end side of things. So I suppose cross-site would not be an issue.

Comment: then why are you using JavaScript to get the content type? shouldn't the server give you that sort of information in a cleaner way?

Comment: I currently don't have access to back-end code/functionality, so this is why I'm looking for a front-end way to grab the mime-type, if there is a way that the server exposes the mime-type naturally to the front-end then I'd like to hear it 'cause right now I'm at a dead-end.

Answer (score 1):

IE supports `document.mimeType`, but it seems to give a friendly name not the actual foo/bar syntax.  Which is wierd.  Though this may be good enough for your purposes.

I don't know why it isn't documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535862(VS.85).aspx), but the native IHTMLDocument2 interface does document it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752597(VS.85).aspx).  Very strange.

Comment: Unfortunately I have had no luck using the mimeType property.

Comment: It didn't work at all (script error) or it didn't give you what you wanted?

Comment: It didn't give the mime-type of the actual document coming in. Case in point, calling document.mimeType on this page gives me "Firefox document" (I assume this means it's an html document -- so far so good), calling it on a JPEG gives me JPG image, also good, calling it on a pdf gives me an error: "Internet Explorer cannot download. Unspecified Error" -- many of the docs we get are in different formats including these.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
var frame = document.getElementById('iframeID');  
var type;  

if (frame.contentDocument) { 
  type = frame.contentDocument.contentType;  
} else {
  type = frame.contentWindow.document.contentType;  
}
alert(type);
```

Sorry end of day no time to test....

Comment: Unfortunately not, again it's the contentType property -- if you enter the following javascript into the address bar for this page: "javascript: alert(document.contentType);" and then press "Enter" - in IE you'll get "undefined", in firefox you'll get "text/html".